# (Modern) OpenGL Different Colored Faces on a Cube - Using Shaders

Tags: opengl, shader, cube

A cube with different colored faces in intermediate mode is very simple. But doing this same thing with shaders seems to be quite a challenge.

I have read that in order to create a cube with different coloured faces, I should create 24 vertices instead of 8 vertices for the cube - in other words, (I visualies this as 6 squares that don't quite touch).

Is perhaps another (better?) solution to texture the faces of the cube using a real simple texture a flat color - perhaps a 1x1 pixel texture?

My texturing idea seems simpler to me - from a coder's point of view.. but which method would be the most efficient from a GPU/graphic card perspective?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your texture idea? It's not clear to me how using a one-color single-pixel texture will help you with a different color on each side of the cube. (e.g. Would you break up the six faces into six different draw calls?)

Comment: @Kaganar: I may be proposing something that is not possible because I haven't played with textures before. All I know is that a texture (bitmap image of some sort) is usually transformed onto a 3D face.. so if that bitmaps was an image of one single colour, then perhaps that could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your overall goal is (e.g. what you're learning to do in the long term), but generally for high performance applications (e.g. games) your goal is to reduce GPU load. Every time you switch certain states (e.g. change textures, render targets, shader uniform values, etc..) the GPU stalls reconfiguring itself to meet your demands.

So, you can pass in a 1x1 pixel texture for each face, but then you'd need six draw calls (usually not so bad, but there is some prep work and potential cache misses) and six texture sets (can be very bad, often as bad as changing shader uniform values).

Suppose you wanted to pass in one texture and use that as a texture map for the cube. This is a little less trivial than it sounds -- you need to express each texture face on the texture in a way that maps to the vertices. Often you need to pass in a texture coordinate for each vertex, and due to the spacial configuration of the texture this normally doesn't end up meaning one texture coordinate for one spatial vertex.

However, if you use an [environmental/reflection map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping), the complexities of mapping are handled for you. In this way, you could draw a single texture on all sides of your cube. (Or on your sphere, or whatever sphere-mapped shape you wanted.) I'm not sure I'd call this easier since you have to form the environmental texture carefully, and you still have to set a different texture for each new colors you want to represent -- or change the texture either via the GPU or in step with the GPU, and that's tricky and usually not performant.

Which brings us back to the canonical way of doing as you mentioned: use vertex values -- they're fast, you can draw many, many cubes very quickly by only specifying different vertex data, and it's easy to understand. It really is the best way, and how GPUs are designed to run quickly.

### Additionally..

And yes, you can do this with just shaders... But it'd be ugly and slow, and the GPU would end up computing it per each pixel.. Pass the object space coordinates to the fragment shader, and in the fragment shader test which side you're on and output the corresponding color. Highly not recommended, it's not particularly easier, and it's definitely not faster for the GPU -- to change colors you'd again end up changing uniform values for the shaders.

Comment: Thanks - I will stick with using vertices. I'm trying to do is take models from an old (90's) 3D game which describes the object in terms of vertices, vertice indices (faces), and face colors. I will have to convert all of the legacy object vertices into more vertices first (e.g, taking the list of 8 cube vertices, creating 4 vertices and a new set of face vertex definitions). I was hoping there would be a simpler way to colour faces of simple graphics objects with a single colour.